# What is Fauxlivia guilty of in the revised timeline of Season 4?

Tags: fringe

In the original timeline of Season 3, we know there's a war between the two universes, that Olivia crosses over to save Peter, gets kidnapped, and Fauxlivia impersonates her in the Over Here universe. When she gets discovered, a lot of the animosity towards her is caused by the fact she slept with Peter, in a classic "mistaken identity/evil twin" trope.

However, in the revised timeline of Season 4, there was no Peter. We still know the war between the two universes happened, and we're told Olivia still got kidnapped and replaced by Fauxlivia.

My question is: is that *all* Fauxlivia did? Just impersonate Olivia? Why does everyone on the Fringe team still seem to hate her, then? Walter calls her a "viper" and a "prostitute" (in his humorous roundabout way). Why would Walter consider her that, if the whole deal with Peter never happened?

I realize this was probably just a throwaway joke, and the hatred didn't last long anyway, but maybe I missed something...

Comment: Ooh! Good point!  I'm curious if an answer even exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have seen that every other event that happened in seasons 1 to 3 still happened, but were revised so that someone or something other than Peter was the cause. Fauxlivia originally seduced Peter, but he was largely just a convenient opening into the Fringe division in our universe. Her primary task was to get information about them for the war.

Thus, the actual crime that she was guilty of, pre and post reset, was being an enemy spy. She also impersonated a real agent, which is probably an even bigger crime. We have to assume, like everything else in S4, that Fauxlivia still did all of those things and the team still hate her for it.

As for Walter's crack about being a prostitute, though it may have just been a writing slip, forgetting that he wouldn't remember her seducing his son, is easily explained if we assume that seduction is just one of Fauxlivia's standard intel-gathering techniques, and there are other men around she could have used them on.

Comment: It's worth noting that without Peter around, Walter and Olivia probably were more dependent on each other.  This would make Fauxlivia's betrayal more personal to alt-timeline Walter.

Comment: This makes sense (I believe it's a writing slip that can actually be patched into making sense). Also, it seems to me Fauxlivia-2 cannot have done anything too unforgivable in the revised timeline, since the Fringe team eventually warms up to her.

Comment: "We have seen that every other event that happened in seasons 1 to 3 still happened" - really? The discussion about the observers from 1x04 has not taken place, 1x16 has not happened (the events happen a few years later in 4x16), 1x17 surrounding Nick Lane has not happened (he is unknown in 4x20), everything related to Robert David Jones has not happened, and everything requiring Walter's presence outside of the lab has not happened, either. Wasn't the impression created by season 4 rather than most things from seasons 1 to 3 have *not* happened?

Comment: "... and there are other men around she could have used them on."  My understanding was that she seduced Walter himself.

Comment: @Keen That's almost an answer by itself.